# Split the window in 4 parts but removing one picture changes layout.

Tags: html, css

I would like to split the window in 4 equal parts. In each part I want a picture which is both aligned vertically and horizontally, a bit like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TFCM4/1/).

The problem is that when I remove one of the pictures, I don't want to other pictures to use that removed picture's space, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TFCM4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TFCM4/8/**

Create 4 divs inside a container (`#bgs`), and add descriptive class names to the elements.

Relevant CSS:

```
html, body { /* Prevent "borders" from appearing */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#bgs { /* Let the container fill the whole window */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#bgs > div { /* Set the height and width of each div to 50% */
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
.right {float: right;} /* Align to the right */
.left {float:left;} /* Align to the left */
img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%; /* Let the image stretch/shrink when necessary*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="bgs">
    <div class="top left">
        <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6235/6257586214_7989986f50_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="top right">
        <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6235/6257586214_7989986f50_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="bottom left">
        <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6235/6257586214_7989986f50_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="bottom right">
        <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6235/6257586214_7989986f50_z.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I've only used the `left` and `right` class names. The `top` and `bottom` have been added to make the source look more readable.

---

*Previous (table) approach:*

Add `visiblity:hidden;` to the images which should be hidden. This property makes the element invisible, but keeps the spot "reserved".

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TFCM4/2/**

Instead of using two tables, you can merge the tables to one table, and achieve the desired result without messing further. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TFCM4/3/**

HTML structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. How can I get the four parts to cover the whole window? At the moment they are all squashed towards the top-left hand corner. Somehow the table is taking as little space as possible, and I want the pictures spread out.

Comment: @Randomblue Simply add `height:100%;width:100%` to the table.

Comment: This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TFCM4/4/ automatically adjusts horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: @Randomblue Updated answer with another approach *without tables*. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TFCM4/8/**

Comment: Cheers. The problem now is that I can't get vertical align and preserve the aspect ratio! See http://jsfiddle.net/TFCM4/9/

Answer (score 0):

Use tables and put the img in TD